# BIND настройка зоны прямого просмотра

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Здравствуйте. Поставил bind, настроил зону прямого и обратного просмотра для доменного имени и возник вопрос.
Вот настройки для зоны прямого просмотра:

```
$TTL    604800
@           IN      SOA     sss.example.com. root.sss.example.com. ( 
                            20150120        ; Serial
                             604800         ; Refresh
                              86400         ; Retry
                            2419200         ; Expire
                             604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@           IN      NS      srv-bind9.example.com.
@           IN      A       192.168.0.1 
@           IN      AAAA    ::1      
sss         IN      A       192.168.0.1
```

При проверке

```
nslookup example.org
```

возвращается стандартный ответ

```
Server:127.0.1.1
Address:127.0.1.1#53

Name: example.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Но я не могу понять, как вернуть другой адрес на example.com, не localhost. Читал, что это делается с помощью А-записи, но не могу понять как её именно тут прописать и в правильном ли вообще направлении я копаю.

Comment: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-bind-zone.html

Comment: убедитесь, что это именно настроенный вами экземпляр bind-а отвечает, сравнив вывод `$ nslookup -querytype=soa example.com` с вашей конфигурацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.(спасибо за совет с сравнением вывода). Дело в том, что bind-у мешал dnsmasq, который был установлен вместе с системой.Проверить это можно командой

```
netstat -lpna | grep :53
```

Удалив dnsmasq, bind сразу заработал как-нужно.